# How would I change a person's birthday with sed if I'm provided with just the name?

Tags: linux, command-line, sed

The line I want to modify is Popeye's birthday
and we have to do it by assuming the we don't know his birthday.

Here's what I did but it doesn't work.

```
sed '/Popeye/s/[0-9]\/[0-9][0-9]\/[0-9][0-9]/[1][1]\/[1][4]\/[4][6]' DDdatebook
```

Input:

```
Popeye Sailor:156-454-3322:945 Bluto Street, Anywhere, USA 29358:3/19/35:22350
```

Comment: what's your expected output?

Answer (score 2):

```
sed '/Popeye/ s#:[0-9]\{1,2\}/[0-9]\{1,2\}/\([0-9]\{2\}\)\{1,2\}:#:[1][1]/[1][4]/[4][6]:#' YourFile
```

- you forget the last delelimiter
- I suggest to use another one than `/`because of the presence in pattern, i select `#` in this case so internal `/` does not have to be escaped.
- I add a extensive pattern for number allow 1 or 2 digit for day/month and 2 or 4 dgit for year (this last seems to be 2 only but in case or remove this second option)

Comment: @AnthonyCalmaRibao: Please note that SO discourages the use of 'SMS-ese' — such as `ty u so much` (which surely doesn't need both the `y` and the first `u`, does it?).

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can change it using `awk`

```
awk -F: '/Popeye/ {$4="01/01/01"}1' OFS=: file
Popeye Sailor:156-454-3322:945 Bluto Street, Anywhere, USA 29358:01/01/01:22350
```

If you like another date, just change this section `"01/01/01"`

To write it back to original file:

```
awk -F: '/Popeye/ {$4="01/01/01"}1' OFS=: file > tmp && mv tmp file
```

Comment: nice, awk is the next thing were going to learn but imma hold onto this ty :)